# Extract the item at a specific location in an R tibble

Tags: r, tibble

```
library(tibble)
x <- tibble(c('a','b','c'))
```

How do I extract the value of `x[1,]`? If I set `x1 <- x[1,]`, it gives me a 1x1 tibble. I do not want that. I want just the value, 'a'.

Comment: Try: `x[1,1,drop=T]`

Comment: Could also try `x[[1,1]]`. If used together with `dplyr`, check `pull`